# load vector from large vector with simd based on mask

Tags: c++11, simd, avx, avx2

I hope someone can help here.

I have a large byte vector  from which i create a small byte vector ( based on a mask ) which I then process with simd.

Currently the mask is an array of baseOffset + submask (byte[256]) , optimized for storage as there are > 10^8 .  I create a maxsize subvector , then loop through the mask array multiply the baseOffssetby 256 and for each bit offset in the mask load from the large vector  and put the values in a smaller vector sequentially .  The smaller vector is then processed via a number of VPMADDUBSW and accumulated .  I can change this structure. eg walk the bits once to use a 8K bit array buffer and then create the small vector.

Is there a faster way i can create the subarray ?

I pulled the code out of the app into a test program but the original is in a state of flux ( moving to AVX2 and pulling more out of C# )

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <mmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>


//from 
char N[4096] = { 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
//W
char W[4096] = { 1, 2, -3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };

char buffer[4096] ; 





__declspec(align(2))
struct packed_destination{
    char blockOffset;
    __int8   bitMask[32];

};

__m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
packed_destination packed_destinations[10];



void  process128(__m128i u, __m128i s)
{
    __m128i calc = _mm_maddubs_epi16(u, s); // pmaddubsw 
    __m128i loints = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(calc);
    __m128i hiints = _mm_cvtepi16_epi32(_mm_shuffle_epi32(calc, 0x4e));
    sum = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_add_epi32(loints, hiints), sum);
}

void process_array(char n[], char w[], int length)
{
    sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
    int length128th  = length >> 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < length128th; i++)
    {
        __m128i u = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&n[i * 128]);
        __m128i s = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&w[i * 128]);
        process128(u, s);
    }
}


void populate_buffer_from_vector(packed_destination packed_destinations[], char n[]  , int  dest_length)
{
    int buffer_dest_index = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < dest_length; i++)
    {
        int blockOffset = packed_destinations[i].blockOffset <<8 ;
        // go through mask and copy to buffer
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
        {
           int joffset = blockOffset  + j << 3; 
            int mask = packed_destinations[i].bitMask[j];
            if (mask & 1 << 0)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<0 ];
            if (mask & 1 << 1)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<1];
            if (mask & 1 << 2)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<2];
            if (mask & 1 << 3)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +   1<<3];
            if (mask & 1 << 4)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<4];
            if (mask & 1 << 5)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<5];
            if (mask & 1 << 6)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset + 1<<6];
            if (mask & 1 << 7)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<7];
        };

    }


}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        packed_destinations[0].bitMask[i] = 0x0f;
        packed_destinations[1].bitMask[i] = 0x04;
    }
    packed_destinations[1].blockOffset = 1;

    populate_buffer_from_vector(packed_destinations, N, 1);
    process_array(buffer, W, 256);

    int val = sum.m128i_i32[0] +
        sum.m128i_i32[1] +
        sum.m128i_i32[2] +
        sum.m128i_i32[3];
    printf("sum is %d"  , val);
    printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Normally mask usage would be 5-15% for some work loads it would be 25-100% .

MASKMOVDQU is close but then we would have to re pack /swl according to the mask before saving..

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the existing code.

Comment: Your `process128` function looks broken - it doesn't actually use the arguments passed to it ?

Comment: fixed .. i pulled the function out so i can make a avx2 .process256

Comment: We probably need to know how sparse the mask is. If the mask is not particularly sparse it might be more efficient to just iterate through the large vector and mask out elements from the sum as needed (using SIMD). At the other extreme, if the mask is sufficiently sparse then you can probably make the `create_array` function a lot more efficient.

Comment: Its  a sparse matrix .. and the usual col : row arrays are too costly in terms of memory so im using the masks.. Normally usage would be  5-15%  occasionally it would be 25-100% . N is  up to 64K  which should be in L2.   buffer is in the 500-3000 range so packed_destinations is ideally 2 - 6  but  while the mask will be concentrated in blocks it will not be ideal i'm assuming packed_destinations length is 6-20 .   Create array is currently in c# and its where i expect inefficiencies can be removed.

Comment: fixed offset , Paul is it possible to do this .The j loop could be a 1 to 256 bit loop using shifting more.

Comment: I only see one small optimisation for the above code, which is to reduce the number of branches in `populate_buffer_from_vector`. However the whole thing smells like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're making assumptions about what the solution should look like, whereas there might be a much better solution if you backed up and looked at the whole problem afresh. Maybe you could explain the *purpose* of this code from a higher level perspective, without assuming how it will be implemented ?

Comment: The purpose of this code is machine learning / ANN . These are traditionally implemented as large matrices with the weights ( W) being the values and the row /column being  the neuron #.  This works fine with small networks but  has some major issues in terms of modelling and performance and the usual solution is to throw super computers at it.

Comment: Anyway all im trying to do is store the source ( which is the output ) into an array of inputs based on maps..    Its like a sparse matrix ( which normally cost 3.5 bytes per connection instead of 2-2.5 here with the mask)  ..

Comment: OK - a couple of suggestions below. Where are you currently performance-wise, i.e. how long does your code currently take to run and how much faster do you need it to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of optimisations for your existing code:

If your data is sparse then it would probably be a good idea to add an additional test of each 8 bit mask value prior to testing the additional bits, i.e.

```
        int mask = packed_destinations[i].bitMask[j];
        if (mask != 0)
        {
            if (mask & 1 << 0)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<0 ];
            if (mask & 1 << 1)
                buffer[buffer_dest_index++] = n[joffset +  1<<1];
            ...
```

Secondly your `process128` function can be optimised considerably:

```
inline __m128i process128(const __m128i u, const __m128i s, const __m128i sum)
{
    const __m128i vk1 = _mm_set1_epi16(1);
    __m128i calc = _mm_maddubs_epi16(u, s);
    calc = _mm_madd_epi16(v, vk1);
    return _mm_add_epi32(sum, calc);
}
```

Note that as well as reducing the SSE instruction count from 6 to 3, I've also made `sum` a parameter, to get away from any dependency on global variables (it's always a good idea to avoid globals, not only for good software engineering but also because they can inhibit certain compiler optimisations).

It would be interesting to see a profile of your code (using a decent sampling profiler, not via instrumentation), since this would help to prioritise any further optimisation efforts.

Comment: thanks paul. didnt realize globals inhibit opt. Was also wondering trade off of existing pop vector vs some sort of masked move into reg then remove the space via_mm256_shuffle_epi8.. 1000s of individual  byte moves make me nervous but should be level 1 cache will profile but have a lot of code to rewrite  and provide some structure. Current code is 100% c# converting the heavy lifting to c. No absolute performance but the faster the more neurons i can use which improves accuracy.If i can get from 70 to 85%  it will be a big win.

Comment: OK - come back after you've tried stuff out and ask a new question with your latest code, benchmarks and a profile and we can see what further optimisations might be possible.